# Is there a way to restart an Replication Task in DMS without recreating the task itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-dms

I'm getting this error when trying to restart my DMS Replication TASK with `start_replication_task` [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.start_replication_task:) method:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombinationException) when calling 
the StartReplicationTask operation: 
Start Type : START_REPLICATION, valid only for tasks running for the first time
```

To solve that i'm creating a new task every execution, can i restart that with the same task instead?

Comment: You need to set `StartReplicationTaskType` to `resume-processing`

Comment: @jordanm Yes it's, thanks

Answer (score 4):

you may need to set `StartReplicationTaskType` to `reload-target` if you want to restart the task from beginning or `resume-processing` if you already start task and you want to resume it.

start-replication valid only after you create the task and want to start it

```
StartReplicationTaskType --> Valid Values: start-replication | resume-processing | reload-target
```

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_StartReplicationTask.html#DMS-StartReplicationTask-request-StartReplicationTaskType